# Azure CDN Verizon Premium Redirect to naked domain when called from subdomain

Tags: azure, azure-cdn, edgecast

I would like to perform redirect like this,

`https://subdomain.example.com/something/somefile.xfm?param1=value1` to  `https://example.com/something/somefile.xfm?param1=value1`

I don't know the way of string manipulation that one can do with the Azure Verizon Edgecast premium service.

Answer (score 0):

Create a rule like this:

```
IF 'always'
Features:
    'URL Redirect': source pattern: "(*.)", Destination: "https://example.com/$1"
```

Comment: Do I need to do that for each cname that is hosted on that endpoint? Is there anyway I can do that for all cnanames by manipulating host variable?